# flask jsonify returns returns Decimal object as string instead of float

Tags: python, json, flask

The `jsonify` function in flask seems to return strings for all `Decimal` values instead of floats. Is there a builtin way to go around this?

In the meantime, I've had to manually remap it, but would like to avoid this if possible

```
from decimal import Decimal

result = {
    k: (float(v) if isinstance(v, Decimal) else v)
    for k, v in result.items() 
}

return jsonify(result)
```

Comment: `Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable` You may use a `Float`.

Comment: You would lose precision on your Decimal if converted to a float. Decimal is initialized with a base 10 string for accuracy

Answer (score 0):

I dont get this error, what exactly are you trying to return?

```
from flask import jsonify
from decimal import Decimal
v = Decimal(0.1)
return jsonify({"0.1": float(v)})
```

-->

```
{
    "0.1": 0.1
}
```

without conversion:

```
v = Decimal(0.1)
return jsonify({"0.1": v})
```

```
{
    "0.1": 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
}
```

Also, make sure you check the "raw data" of the return, not the prettyprinted or some other format that your browser might use.